# Why am I getting a 'Invalid Hooks' error when using React router bootstap's LinkContainer?

Tags: react-hooks, react-router, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a navbar using react-router-bootstrap but keep getting an invalid hooks error when I try to use the LinkContainer. Not having used react-router-bootstrap before, I wrote a quick test app:

Here is my App.js:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import TestChart from './components/TestChart';
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Home from './components/Home';
// import './global.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Test!</h1>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="TestChart" element={<TestChart />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

Hear is my Navbar/Header component:

```
import React from "react";
import {Navbar, Nav} from 'react-bootstrap'; 
import { LinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap";


const Header = () => {
    return (
        <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
            <h1>Test Navbar</h1>
            <Navbar.Brand>My Chart App</Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                    <LinkContainer to="/TestChart">
                        <Nav.Link>Test Chart</Nav.Link >
                    </LinkContainer>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

I have the following installed in the project:

```
├── @reduxjs/toolkit@1.6.2
├── @testing-library/jest-dom@5.15.0
├── @testing-library/react@11.2.7
├── @testing-library/user-event@12.8.3
├── bindings@1.5.0 extraneous
├── bootstrap@5.1.3
├── chart.js@3.6.1
├── chartjs@0.3.24
├── file-uri-to-path@1.0.0 extraneous
├── history@5.1.0
├── nan@2.15.0 extraneous
├── react-bootstrap@2.0.3
├── react-chartjs-2@4.0.0
├── react-dom@17.0.2
├── react-redux@7.2.6
├── react-router-bootstrap@0.26.0
├── react-router-dom@6.0.2
├── react-router@6.0.2
├── react-scripts@4.0.3
├── react@17.0.2
└── web-vitals@1.1.2
```

Whenever I coment out the LinkContainer, the app compiles and renders in the browser. I have no idea why it's throwing a invalid hooks error when I use the LinkContainer.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue. I copy/pasted your code into this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-am-i-getting-a-invalid-hooks-error-when-using-react-router-bootstaps-link-zywkp) and adjusted versions to match. I see you have `history` in your project, is that being used? How are you setting up/configuring the app's router?

Comment: No, I have't set up history yet. Here's my index.js where I set up the Router. 
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import store from './app/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
// import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

Comment: I see. I moved the router to the index file in my linked codesandbox but it still doesn't reproduce any error messages. Think you can try creating a codesandbox of your own that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: I just played with the Code sandbox and can't reproduce the error, either. In fact, everything that I copied and pasted in that was in my app, works perfectly, which is curious. The only difference is that I'm using redux, but I can't see how that would cause the error. I'm wondering if it's maybe a node version thing? I'm running 14.17.6. I pushed the sandbox to my github and am gonna try to run it locally and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I wouldn't suspect node being an issue here, but maybe something with the Redux. Can you try also adding Redux to the CSB?

Comment: I pulled the sandbox to my local machine and installed reux, but still couldn't reproduce the error. Everything works as it should! Bizarre. But, I now have the bones for my app, so I'm just going to run with it. I am falling behind schedule, so don't have time to chase squirrels

Comment: Thanks for your help, though!!! I don't know what was wrong but have a working app now, so I'm happy. When I have more time, I'll dig in to it more.

Comment: Great, cheers and good luck!